# GROUP BY results of a grouped query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to select the number of free beds per floor and the number of rooms in which those beds exist. I think I'm having trouble because I first have to calculate how many beds are free in each room, which I'm doing by subtracting the number of beds in the room minus the people that are assigned to that room.

Can I `GROUP BY` the current query in a way that achieves the desired result?

The tables used are these:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planta(
    codigo int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    especialidad varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS habitacion(
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    numero_camas int NOT NULL,
    planta_id int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (planta_id) REFERENCES planta(codigo)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS paciente(
    dni varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    num_ss varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    direccion varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    tratamiento mediumtext NOT NULL,
    diagnostico mediumtext NOT NULL,
    habitacion_id int NOT NULL,
    medico_id int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (habitacion_id) REFERENCES habitacion(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (medico_id) REFERENCES medico(num_colegiado)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The query is this:

```
SELECT planta.codigo AS Floor_id,
       habitacion.id AS Room_id,
       numero_camas - count(dni) AS Free_beds 
FROM habitacion, paciente, planta 
WHERE planta_id = planta.codigo AND habitacion_id = habitacion.id 
GROUP BY planta.codigo, habitacion.id;
```

It returns this result:

```
Floor id | Room id | Free beds
    1         1          1    
    1         2          1    
    2         3          3
```

But I want this:

```
Floor id | Rooms | Free beds
    1        2         2    
    2        1         3
```

Comment: When dealing with multiple tables, always qualify all columns. Which table contains `numero_camas`? Which `dni`? Please don't only show the results, but also what the separate tables contain.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for your feedback, Kettner. Now I have added the tables that belong to this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

You just need the correct `GROUP BY` logic.  I think it is like this

```
SELECT pl.codigo AS Floor_id, count(count distinct h.id) as num_rooms,
       MAX(numero_camas) - count(distinct h.id) AS Free_beds 
FROM habitacion h join
     paciente p
     on p.habitacion_id = h.id   -- just a guess that this is the right join condition
     planta pl
     on h.planta_id = pl.codigo
GROUP BY pl.codigo
```

Comment: Thnk you, Gordon. I tried the solution, but I'm still not getting the correct result. Right now I'm getting: `Floor id=1, num rooms=3, free beds=0` and `Floor id=2, num rooms=1, free beds=3`. I think it might have to do something with the calculation of how many beds are free, althought I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: **Update:** I checked you edited the code in the answer. Now it works perfectly. I will keep improving and I will try to fully understand the solution you provided. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Gordon Linoff and yor statement I guess with this minor changes you should get the correct result (I guess the distinct rooms need to be counted and the amount of beds minus the people that are assigned needs to be summed up):

```
SELECT 
     pl.codigo AS Floor_id,  
     count(distinct habitacion_id) as num_rooms, 
     SUM(numero_camas - count(dni)) AS Free_beds 
FROM habitacion h 
join paciente p on p.habitacion_id = h.id 
join condition planta pl on h.planta_id = pl.codigo 
GROUP BY pl.codigo
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two aggregations: The number of beds per habitation, then the sum of available beds per floor. One way to do this is:

```
select planta_id, count(*) as rooms, sum(available - occupied) as free_beds
from
(
  select
    planta_id,
    h.id as habitacion_id,
    numero_camas as available,
    (select count(*) from paciente p where p.habitacion_id = h.id) as occupied
  from habitacion h
) habitation_aggregated
group by planta_id
order by planta_id;
```

You see that I have a subquery in the `FROM` clause that represents an aggregation. This is a very good and save way to deal with multiple aggregations.